# Require not working ( SystemJS)

Tags: systemjs

I am very new to systemJS and trying to explore it. 
Cant we call require as shown in the below inside HTML. When i call require() function inside JS files it loads JS file properly but inside HTML file it does not work..

Below is the SystemJS code on my HTML

```
System.config({ map: { Customerx: 'Customer.js' }  });

SystemJS.import('Customerx').then(function (m) {
var x = require("Customerx"); //<-- this works inside JS files but not here why  });
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, you should detail exactly how it does not work. What is the undesirable behavior you are getting? What do you expect?

Comment: I have got the answer and also marked the answer. I am very surprised even after putting code and clear reason the question has been marked as not clear.
One of the reasons why SO is loosing its charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this issue. Require() is not available on the windows its scoped in each file.

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1442